# How can I get the string value of a key for a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First of all, I don't want the index or any value in the object. I've used a function to group these elements from a json file. When displaying them on the page, I want a section heading that displays the "key" of the pair. So one section will say Tanning Standup and Tanning LayDown with it's children inside of it. Is there a way to do that?

```
{
   "Tanning StandUp": [
      "20 Sessions",
      "10 Sessions",
      "5 Sessions",
      "1 Session",
      "Unlimited Tanning for 1 Month"
   ],
   "Tanning LayDown": [
      "20 Sessions",
      "10 Sessions",
      "5 Sessions",
      "1 Session",
      "Unlimited Tanning for 1 Month"
   ],
}
```

**vueFile.vue**

```js
<section v-bind:key="category.ID" v-for="category in byCategory">
    {{byCategory}}
    <p v-bind:key="item.ID" v-for="item of category">{{item}}</p>

_______________________

  computed: {
    byCategory() {
      return this.servicesJson.reduce((acc, user) => {
        (acc[user.Category] = acc[user.Category] || []).push(user.Item);

        return acc;
      }, {});
    }
  }
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

> You can also provide a second argument for the property’s name (a.k.a. key).

So something like `v-for="(category, key) in byCategory"` should work in your case.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I brushed over that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Most framework-specific functions are almost identical to existing JS functions (especially if you consider ES6), so the ideas on how to solve things are usually the same.